# Changing inequality type when taking the limit of an expression

Tags: limits, derivatives

Reading about the demonstration of the theorem  that states that growing functions $f(x)$ differentiable and growing in $[a,b]$ have non-negative derivative, I have found the following demonstration:

$$\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$$
Positive for $\Delta x>0$ and negative for $\Delta x<0$

Then

1. $$\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}> 0$$
   an as a consequence
2. $$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f((x)}{\Delta x} \geq 0$$

q.e.d.

In going from 1) to 2) how did we get the inequality changing from $>0$ to $\geq0$?

Comment: Consider $a_n = \frac{n}{n+1}$. Then $a_n < 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. But for the limit we have equality.

Comment: An example is the function $f(x) = x^3$ on $[-1,1].$ The derivative is $f'(x)=3x^2.$ Then the derivative at $x=0$ is $f'(0) = 3\times 0^2 = 0.$

Comment: @DanielFischer But in this case, won't the limit lead to $\frac{0}{0}$ which is indeterminate?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. When you look at a difference quotient in order to get a derivative, then you can't separate the limits, as the limit of the numerator and the denominator each are $0$. But that's irrelevant to the question here why the strict inequality for all the quotients only guarantees a non-strict inequality for the limit. That's because one can approach a point from strictly one side, so each individual approximation (difference quotient, term of sequence) lies strictly on one side of the limit. But the limit doesn't, of course, it is equal to itself.